# AWS SAM specify Method Request in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I am fairly new to AWS SAM. I have implemented an API Gateway using AWS web console and specified the body validation in the API method request, I want to achieve the same thing but using SAM template. My search for how to specify Method Request in API Gateway SAM template gave nothing related to this. Any Help please?

Comment: what exactly are you looking to configure using method request screen

Answer (score 3):

Complete guide to add validations on API gateway [here](https://sarthakj178.com/add-validations-to-aws-api-gateway-methods/).

Below is a code snippet from SAM template.yaml to add body validations on a sample API. Here a PingInput API model is defined onthe /ping path on the API. The Model contains one required and one optional parameter. Calling the API without the required parameter will fail.

```
AuthApiGateway:
     Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
     Properties:
         StageName: Prod
         DefinitionBody:
             swagger: '2.0'
             info:
                 version: '1.0'
                 title: 'AwsRestServiceTemplate'
             paths:
                 /ping:
                     x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
                         responses: {}
                     post:
                         x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: 'Validate body' # To specify that the Http Post body needs to be validated
                         parameters:
                             - in: 'body'
                                 name: 'PingInput'
                                 required: true
                                 schema:
                                     $ref: '#/definitions/PingInput'
                         x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                             httpMethod: post
                             type: aws_proxy
                             uri:
                                 Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PingFunction.Arn}/invocations
             x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
                 Validate body:
                     validateRequestParameters: true
                     validateRequestBody: true
             definitions:
                 PingInput:
                     type: 'object'
                     required:
                         - 'requiredKey'
                     properties:
                         requiredKey:
                             type: 'string'
                         optionalKey:
                             type: 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to configure `authorization", here is the SAM template.

```
MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: MyFunction
    ...
    Events:
      Post:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /compute
          Method: POST
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
          Auth:
            Authorizer: AWS_IAM
```

You have to define the authorizer inside `AWS::Serverless::Api` definition and use it inside the function.

References:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_aws_iam_auth/template.yaml

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_cognito_auth/template.yaml